# Matching nested generic type

Tags: generics, rust

For the sake of learning I'm writing my own functor implementation. Function-wise it makes no sense, but it acts as a nice way to learn how the language works and how to implement more complex structures with it. But I'm stuck in how to implement a `flatten` function where I'd like to take a possible inner wrapper layer and remove it. My implementation is as

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Functor<T> {
  Functor(T),
}

type MapFn<T, S> = dyn Fn(T) -> S;

impl<T> Functor<T> {
    fn map<S>(self, operation: &MapFn<T, S>) -> Functor<S> {
      use Functor::Functor;

      match self {
          Functor(value) => Functor::<S>(operation(value))
      }
    }

    fn unwrap(self) -> T {
      use Functor::Functor;

      match self {
          Functor(value) => value
      }
    }

    fn flatten(self) -> Functor<T> {
      use Functor::Functor;

      // TODO: now just returns same instance
      // if the type inside is another functor, should "peel" one layer off,
      // otherwise if just value of <T>, should return self
      self
    }
}
```

Compiler does understand the wrapped types and for example `unwrap` works just fine in the following code

```rust
let fff = Functor(Functor(123));
println!("The value from wrapped functor is {:?}", fff.unwrap().unwrap())
```

I just can't wrap my head around on how to implement this so that the compiler is happy with the types. I tried to look into source code for similar functors from core types such as `Option` and `Result`, but they operate differently. `Option` for example uses matching to check for `None`.

Examples I've found online for destructuring wrapped types tend to have for example struct with an enum inside, but here the types are same, but with different generics param, so for example compiler does not pass something like

```
fn flatten(self) -> Functor<T> {
      use Functor::Functor;

      match self {
          Functor(Functor(T)) => ...,
      }
}
```

All I get is mismatched types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Option` type, the `flatten` function is implemented on the `Option<Option<T>>` type, so for your custom functor you would have a separate `impl` block like so to indicate this method only applies to a `Functor` with an inner type of another `Functor`:

```rust
impl<T> Functor<Functor<T>> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Functor<T> {
        use Functor::Functor;
        match self {
            Functor(val) => val,
        }
    }
}
```

This tells the compiler that the inner type is also a `Functor`, so it knows it can destructure as a `Functor(Functor(val))`.

This only allows flattening one layer at a time, which is the same as the `Option` type.

Comment: Nice! Works even better than I expected, since the compiler will notice a situation where there isn't an inner layer to "peel" i.e. just a value, and will prevent from calling `flatten` on such an variable.